# Insert records from one database to amother database using SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert records from `CustomerManagmentDB` to a new database that I created called `Practiceone` using the following SQL execute command but failed to do so.

```
USE [Practiceone];
GO

INSERT [Suppliers]
(
    [SupplierID],
    [SupplierName],
    [ContactName],
    [Address],
    [City],
    [PostalCode],
    [Country],
    [Phone]
)
SELECT
        [SupplierID],
        [SupplierName],
        [ContactName],
        [Address],
        [City],
        [PostalCode],
        [Country],
        [Phone]
    FROM
        [CustomerManagementDB].[dbo].[Suppliers]
    WHERE
        [supplierID] = 22;
```

Comment: this must be a duplicate!

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of converting your question to english and TSQL. I'd like you to respond to this comment and learn something from my efforts. Most importantly I'd like you to take as much effort writing your questions as I've taken fixing yours. Please, never post such an ill formatted question again and expect a resonable response. I very much suspect that if you copy the improved code from the question it has a better chance of working.

Comment: However, I suspect that now that you have what you wanted, you won't bother so shortly I will down vote this question and vote to close it because that is what it deserved. I await your urgent response.

Comment: Thank you@Jodrell. Please delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the column name in insert should not have quote

```
    insert into Suppliers (SupplierID,supplierName,ContactName,
 Address,City,PostalCode,Country,Phone)
 select SupplierID,SupplierName,ContactName,Address,City,PostalCode,Country,Phone
 from CustomerManagementDB.dbo.Suppliers
 where supplierID=22
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove single quotes from your insert statement.
e.g.: INSERT INTO Suppliers (SupplierID)...

Your query should be as below :

```
INSERT INTO Suppliers (SupplierID,supplierName,ContactName,Address,City,PostalCode,Country,Phone)
SELECT SupplierID,SupplierName,ContactName,Address,City,PostalCode,Country,Phone FROM CustomerManagementDB.dbo.Suppliers
WHERE SupplierID=22
```